# gdb list functions names equivalent for lldb

Tags: lldb

is possible with `lldb` have a list of functions at runtime like `gdb info functions`? I had a look at help but didn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `lldb` help doesn't explicitly state `gdb`'s `info functions` equivalent, it shows the command mapped from `info function <FUNC_REGEX>`.

Nonetheless, you may realise that `info functions` in `gdb` gives you the same output as `info function .*`, where `.*` is the regular expression that matches every function name.

That being said, from [GDB to LDB command map](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html#executable-and-shared-library-query-commands) you get two corresponding commands:

```
image lookup -r -n <FUNC_REGEX>
```

and

```
image lookup -r -s <FUNC_REGEX>
```

where the first one will find debug symbols matching `<FUNC_REGEX>`, while the second one: non-debug symbols matching this regular expression.

The combination of both with `<FUNC_REGEX>` equal `.*` should give you the desired result.

Comment: Hmm, I just got 
_error: 'info' is not a valid command_ to `(lldb) info function .*`